# Using Layout - Android

Tags: android, layout, view

I have a layout, but I need put more views (Buttons, EditText, etc), but how you know, the layout of the ADT is a bit small and I can't to set more views or know where is it, Somebody know How can I set more of these?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Android isn't like iOS how you can just position elements with drag & drop.

RelativeLayout will position elements relative to each other and LinearLayout will lay out elements sequentially in a linear fashion, either vertically or horizontally. Both methods are better executed by actually writing the View XML yourself.

I suggest reading this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to actually see what you are adding to your layout without messing with the XML you could maybe change the device that the renderer is using to preview your layout.

I don't know what IDE you're using but in Eclipse and Android Studio you can change the device that your layout preview is rendered on. That way you can see what you're adding as you add it.

Then just make sure to put everything in a scroll view so users can access all the views and widgets you've put in that layout for your activity or fragment or dialog or whatever else it is.